# Wrong calculation in Python for overpayment

Tags: python, function, calculation

I started an online training for Python. The assignment wants to me calculate 45 hours work for 10.50 hourly payment. But, 5 hours in this is overwork. So, the payment goes to 10.50 X 5
So, the payment should be 498.75.

But, my program finds different sum. What is wrong with this code? (Note that I am novice)

```
hours = float(input("Enter hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter rate: "))
extraPay = float((hours-40) * (rate*1.5))

def computepay(a, b, c):
    paymentCalc= a * b + c
    return paymentCalc
x = computepay(hours, rate, extraPay)
print(x)
```

Comment: You need to subtract 5 from the hours for the default rate payment. Right now you calculate payment for 45 times normal rate plus 5 times 1.5x rate, which is 52.5 too much.

Comment: First of all you should describe the rules of the calculation more precisely as plain text (edit the question).

Answer (score 0):

you need to substract extra hours from basic hours on calculations and also add check that extra_pay will not be in negative. Do, Like this:

```
hours = float(45)
rate = float(10.5)
extra_hours = float(hours - 40)
extraPay = float(extra_hours * (rate*1.5))


def computepay(a, b, c, d):
    if c < 0:
        c = 0
    payment_calc = (a - d) * b + c
    return payment_calc


x = computepay(hours, rate, extraPay, extra_hours)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the overpay hours twice, once with the increased rate in extraPay and once in your payment calc (a is still 45).
Also, you need to check if hours are less than 40 because if it is less, extraPay will be negative and your calculation will be wrong.

Here is my suggestion:

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    bonus = 0
    if hours>40:
        overtime = hours-40
        hours=40
        bonus = (overtime)*rate*1.5
    return hours*rate+bonus
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
hours = float(input("Enter hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter rate: "))
remainder=(max(0,hours-40))
def computepay(a, b):
        paymentCalc= a * b
        return paymentCalc
def compute_ext(remainder,rate):
        ext = remainder * (rate*1.5)
        return ext
base = computepay(min(40,hours), rate)
if remainder:
        base+=compute_ext(remainder,rate)
print(base)
```

you used all the hours instead for a max of 40 to calculate the base pay